# Process explorer cycle and time not matching

Tags: windows, cpu, process

I have a question about process explorer.

I am checking the performances of two different processes:

> skype cycle : 4,600,000,000 ; skype total cpu time : 5:00.000
>   chrome cycle 200,000,000    ; chrome total cpu time : 1:00.000

The time and the cycle are not supposed to be proportional? If I have like 10 times more cycle I am not supposed to have 10 times the time?

Answer (score 1):

Those two times will not necessarily match as modern CPUs support both [over-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost) and [under-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedstep)clocking and so the amount of clock cycles available per second can vary a great deal.

A process could be running during a fast or slow period and if the task is waiting for a second in a [spin-lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) the actual number of cycles could well be different while the time taken running on a CPU core is the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, process Time and Cycles are not proportional (but wall time to cycles is). I'm looking at a process (notepad++) and its time (kTime/uTime/tTime) are not changing because it is not actively doing anything, but the cycles are continuously updating. if you started two processes at exactly midnight, they would have nearly identical cycle counts the next day, even if one was using a core at 100% all night long, and the other was simply sitting idle using almost no processor time.